Chain rule in differential of Gauss map
This is probably more of a calculus question than a geometry question.
Let $N: S \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ be the Gauss map. And let $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \supseteq U \rightarrow S$ a parameterization of the differential surface $S$. Let $\varphi _u = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}$ and $\varphi _v = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial v}$ and let $d _pN$ be the differential of $N$ in $p=\varphi (u,v)$.
So my professor stated without much explanations that $d _pN(\varphi _u) = \frac{\partial N}{\partial u} (u, v)$.
I see the implicit composition $N \circ \varphi$ however I can't really get this derivation since I don't really know how something like $\frac{\partial N}{\partial \varphi}$ should be.
Any help?
